# How to compute $\int_0^{\infty} x^2 e^{-c x^2} J_0(x)dx$?

Tags: definite-integrals, bessel-functions

How to compute $\int_0^{\infty}x^2e^{-c x^2}J_0(x)dx, c>0$?

It is easy to compute this integral when we replace $x^2$ by $x$. Namely, $$\int_0^{\infty}xe^{-c x^2}J_0(x)dx = \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{4 c}}}{2c}$$ by  using a series expansion for $J_0(x)$.

Today, I put that $x^2$ there, Mathematica still gives the result. It is not clear how this follows from using a similar series expansion.

Comment: There is a general formula: http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.22.E54

Comment: @Gary Thank you, I know it now.